# Questions about Facebook app permissions

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-page, notify

1. Is it possible to change the permissions required by a Facebook app, after it's already been launched?

   If so, what happens with users who already approved the app?
2. What is the recommended way for a Facebook app to "asynchronously" **notify** a user about something?

   Is there a way that requires only the default basic permissions?
3. Can a Facebook app read from / post to a 3rd party's page without the user being an admin of that page?

   If so, will the app require more than the default basic permissions?

Comment: Q2 also refers to notify **another** user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the permissions required by a Facebook app, after it's already been launched? If so, what happens with users who already approved the app?

**Yes**. What do you mean by what happens? Obviously, your app will only use the permissions that the user has granted. That's it. So, you should ask user for the new permissions again.

> What is the recommended way for a Facebook app to "asynchronously" notify a user about something?

That totally depends on what exactly you want and how you implement.

> Is there a way that requires only the default basic permissions?

Don't ask for any extra permissions, that's it!

> Can a Facebook app read from / post to a 3rd party's page without the user being an admin of that page? If so, will the app require more than the default basic permissions?

**Yes**. But, only the public posts you can fetch. And **no** extra permissions are required for this. [Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=cocacola%2Fposts)

Comment: Re 1 - How do I ask user for the new permissions **again**? Will a new php getLoginUrl (specifying the new permissions) do this automatically?

Comment: Simply call `Login` with new `scope` parameters that's it. I would recommend you to read the docs and try the things out that'll help you clearing out your doubts!